# Multivariable calculus problem on unitary disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I came around this problem today:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a differentiable map, constant on the disk $D=\left\{{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1} \right\}$. Prove that for every $X \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ there is a point $P$ such that $\nabla f(P)$ . $X=0$ and $||P|| < 1$.

What I've tried: as it is well known the gradient of a scalar function is perpendicular to the hypersurface $N_c := \left\{{(x,y): f(x,y) = c} \right\}$. So for every $X = (a,b)$ the gradient of the point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(-b,a)$ is going to be perpendicular to $X$. But this doesn't obey to the second condition..

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $D=\left\{{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1} \right\}$ it attains a maximum and a minimum. If both are equal then $f$ is constant and $\nabla f\equiv 0,$ and we have done. In other case the maximum or the minimum is achieved at some point $p$ interior to the disk, that is, $\|p\|<1.$ So, $\nabla f(p)=0$ and the conclusion follows.